# Working with Entities - Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, entity

I´m coding an app that will allow the user to take a picture, add some title and description to it and upload it to Google´s Servers. That package (picture+title+description) is named "Gift". I've used Google´s automated Backend Engine generator and added an @Entity class named Gift.

After taking the picture and clicking on submit, the "Gift" is successfully sent to Google and looking my Google App Engine Dashboard, now I have a Gift with a proper ID, a Blob (image), Description and Title.

Now what I want to do is show all those "Gifts"/Entities on a ListView, so that the user can interact with the "Gifts". What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This question is too vague. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Well, I have the code the retrieve the entities, but they are not objects that I can interact with or retrieve their variables correctly. How can I convert one of those Entities to a object that I can work with?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, here´s the code I´m using:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Filter keyFilter =  new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
                                              FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN,
                                              0);
                Query q =  new Query("Gift").setFilter(keyFilter);
                PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

                    for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()){
                    String title = (String) result.getProperty("title");
                    String description = (String) result.getProperty("description");
                    Blob bmp = (Blob) result.getProperty("bmp");
                    //new Object using variables above
                    }
```

This way I think I can iterate through the results and associate them with new objects of the type Gift.

Comment: This code will retrieve all entities of kind "Gift". You don't need a filter for that. Simply run `Query("Gift");`